# How can I generate a symbols file for my Electron application code?

Tags: electron, symbols, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate

I am using the Electron symbols file to symbolicate my stack trace, and everything is working fine. Except these symbols don't work on my application code. How can I generate a symbols file for my actual application code? I am using Electron builder.

Electron frame work lines in the stack trace are nice and readable:

```
20  Electron Framework  0x11421a0d3  ElectronMain (electron_library_main.mm:23)
```

Stack trace lines which refer to my application code are not

```
21  Clockk  0x10d3059b0  <unknown>
```

Ironically, the symbols file for the Electron framework is useless unless I know the entry point to that error stack within my application code.